# Create root and routes for Devise object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have created an `Admin` model with the Devise gem. Using the Devise controller generator, I now have a `app/controllers/admins` folder containing all the stock controllers for me to modify if I choose, such as `sessions_controller`, `passwords_controller`, etc.

However, I can't figure out how to just get an `Admin` controller and simple `admin` routes like `admin_path` or `new_admin_path`.

Here's my `rake routes | grep admin`

```
               new_admin_session GET      /admin/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 admins/sessions#new
                   admin_session POST     /admin/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 admins/sessions#create
           destroy_admin_session DELETE   /admin/sign_out(.:format)                                                                admins/sessions#destroy
              new_admin_password GET      /admin/password/new(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#new
             edit_admin_password GET      /admin/password/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/passwords#edit
                  admin_password PATCH    /admin/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                                 PUT      /admin/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                                 POST     /admin/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#create
                      admin_root GET      /admin(.:format)                                                                         admins/sessions#portal
                  admin_sign_out GET      /admin/sign_out(.:format)                                                                admin/sessions#destroy
```

And here are the relevant parts of my `routes.rb`

```rb
  devise_for :admins, path: 'admin', controllers: { sessions: 'admins/sessions' }

  devise_scope :admin do
    get "/admin", to: 'admins/sessions#portal', as: 'admin_root'
    get "/admin/sign_out", to: 'admin/sessions#destroy', as: 'admin_sign_out'
  end
```

You'll see that I've currently got a `portal` method in my `Admin::SessionsController`, which is my current workaround. I know the right place for that page is in an `AdminsController` but I can't figure out how to set that up.

Adding `admins: 'admins/admins'` to the `devise_for :admins, controllers:` block doesn't give me any new routes. I tried adding an `AdminsController` with methods but that doesn't help either, trying to go to `/admin/new` or `/admins/new` says no route matches.

Comment: does this paragraph from devise gem  help u? "In the following command you will replace MODEL with the class name used for the application’s users (it’s frequently User but could also be Admin). This will create a model (if one does not exist) and configure it with the default Devise modules. The generator also configures your config/routes.rb file to point to the Devise controller."

Comment: No, that does not help. I generated the Admin resource, all that's telling you is how to choose the name of your resource.

Comment: and the resources get created automatically . no need to define anything.

Comment: No, they don't. There is no resource or routes for just `admin`, as you can see in my routes. They are all `admin_password` or something like that. The two routes you see at the bottom are custom routes that I defined.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but devise does not give you the routes for REST actions like new/edit/update/create, you should also add a `resources :admins` declaration on your routes.

Comment: And you need to create a separate `AdminsController` in `app/controllers`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I have my device and namespaces set up

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :admins, :controllers => { registrations:  'admins/registrations',
                                        sessions:       'admins/sessions',
                                        passwords:      'admins/passwords',
                                        confirmations:  'admins/confirmations'
  }
  authenticate :admin do
    namespace :admins do
      ...
      root 'dashboards#index'
    end
  end
  ...
  root 'pages#index'
```

Now controllers are also important.

```
#app/controllers/admin_controller.rb
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admins/application'
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!
end
```

The Devise controllers I have them set like this

```
#app/controllers/admins/sessions_controller.rb
class Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  layout 'admins/application'
  ...
end
```

Repeat this process for all your other device controllers

Let me know if this helps you out